# Query and Result using AJAX is not working - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```js
var commentCount = 2;
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(commentCount);
});

function more_comment(ele) {
  commentCount = commentCount + 2;
  alert(commentCount);
  $(ele).parent(".comment-section").find(".comments").load("morecomments.php", {
    commentNewCount: commentCount
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-section">
  <div class="comments">
    <?php  
     $sql30 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $post_id ORDER BY comment_id LIMIT 2";
     $result30 = $db->query($sql30);
     if($result30->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row30 = $result30->fetch_assoc()) {
     ?>
    <div class="panel panel-primary comment-show">
      <div class="panel-heading author">
        <?php echo $row30['username']; ?> <span class="text-right pull-right"><?php echo $row30['comment_time']; ?></span></div>
      <div class="panel-body author-comment">
        <?php echo $row30['comment']; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <center><button type="button" class="btn-primary" value="<?php echo $comment_count; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post_id;?>" onclick="more_comment(this);">Show more Comments</button> </center>
</div>

more_comment.php
<?php 
include("connect.php");
$comment_count = $_POST['commentNewCount'];   
$sql30 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $post_id ORDER BY comment_id LIMIT $comment_count";
$result30 = $db->query($sql30);
if($result30->num_rows > 0) {
while($row30 = $result30->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<div class="panel panel-primary comment-show">
  <div class="panel-heading author">
    <?php echo $row30['username']; ?> <span class="text-right pull-right"><?php echo $row30['comment_time']; ?></span></div>
  <div class="panel-body author-comment">
    <?php echo $row30['comment']; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php }
}
?>
```

**Want to Achieve this:** A comment system where initially 2 Comments are only shown and when we click on a button (Show more comments), the comments will be 4 then 6 and so on.

**Problem Facing:** I am using Ajax. there is a function (more_comment()) invoked on button click, where my JQuery load() resides. *morecomments.php* is the URL and I am incrementing the commentCount in Function and send it through POST method. and in morecomments.php file I use this commentCount to query and get back the result. But nothing happens on button click.

**Notes:** I can't simply select an element like $(".comment), since I have multiple comment classes resulted by a loop.
The alerts commentCount is working and shows the correct value on each click!  No XHR Requests in Network Tab!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Does the request get initiated in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: @ccKep There is no XHR request found on clicking the button in Network tab. morecomments.php is the URL and it should execute that script on calling. Right?

Comment: Does the `alert()` from `more_comment` happen?

Comment: Yes. The function is get invoked and everytime I click on the button the alert is showing me correct value. Increments by 2.

Comment: jQuery `.parent` only traverses to the **immediate** parent of the selected object, in this case that's the `<center>` element. Since you're filtering for `.comment-section` the result set is 0 and no elements fire the `.load` method I guess. You're probably looking for `.closest` instead.

Comment: @ccKep Oh.. Ok I will check and post the result here.

Comment: @ccKep I have removed the **<center>** tag and checked!  Now, when I click on the button the already shown comments are disappearing!

Comment: The content gets overwritten when using `.load` - I suspect your XHR returns an empty response? Did you check the response in your network tab?

Comment: Transferred is 1.17Kb and Size is 0B .

Comment: Looks like your `morecomments.php` doesn't output anything.

Comment: @ccKep Thanks for taking time!   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the function and onclick attribute, use event delegation to delegate the click event, use closest to get the closest `.comment-section` div, use the ajax post load will do a get request

```
$('.comment-section').on('click','button',function(){
   $.post("morecomments.php", {
      postId:$(this)attr('data-id'),
      commentNewCount: commentCount
   },function(data){
         $(this).closest(".comment-section").find(".comments").html(data)
   });
})
```

Don't forget to pass the post id in your ajax request

```
$post_id = $_POST['postId'];
```

for the button problem alter your html to

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary getComments" value="<?php echo $comment_count; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post_id;?>" onclick="more_comment(this);">Show more Comments</button>
```

and the code

```
$('.comment-section').on('click','.getComments',function(){
```

Comment: But the *.comment-section* has other buttons! So how to uniquely identify the button in on() function ?

Comment: I will try and revert back.

Comment: I heard using event is better than onclick. Is that really correct ? And for selecting unique button can we replace *button* in your code with the id ? like this : '#btn-id' ??

Comment: i see your new to this , its comma, see updated answer